# How to upload files on mobiles

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, upload

I'm working on a phonegap project using Html5 & Javascript. 
I want the user to upload files. When I add this:

```
 <input id="image-file" type="file" />
```

It works on the web browser, but when I open it on the mobile, it's disabled.

Is there someway to upload files with mobiles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to talk to the native libraries for the specific platform.

For iOS for example, you need access to the photo albums, in order to upload photo's. This needs to be done with the API from phonegap to talk to the iOS native libraries.

Every OS has a specific API to do this. I am not much into phonegap but I know this is there. Perhaps even 1 API for all OS's

Comment: Yeah I remember I tried using it before but I totally forgot about it ... Thanks for reminding me.